# SQL Server 2016: how to get a single row view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have been trying to word this correctly, but here's my [dbfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com)

Table:

```
    Customerkey int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    processdate date NULL,
    CCcount int NULL,
    CHKcount int NULL,
    SACount int NULL
);

INSERT INTO products 
(Customerkey, processdate, CCcount, CHKCount, SACount) 
VALUES
(101,'20210501', 12,3,5),
(102,'20210203', 1,3,1),
(103,'20190412', 4,0,2)

SELECT  CustomerKey,  processdate,
ProductMix=STUFF  
(  
     (  
       SELECT distinct ',' + str(CCcount)  + ',' + str(CHKCount)   +  ',' + str(SACount)
       FROM products t2 
       WHERE t2.CustomerKey = t1.CustomerKey   
       and t2.processdate = t1.processdate
        ),1,1,''  
)  
FROM products t1  
GROUP BY CustomerKey,  processdate

SELECT CustomerKey, processdate,
concat(
Case when CCcount >' ' then 'CCcount' 
when CHKCount > '' then 'CHKCount'
when SACount > '' then 'SACount'
end, '') as Product_Mix_Expanded
from products
```

Expected Output:

| CustomerKey | processdate | Product_Mix | Product_Mix_Expanded |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2021-05-01 | 12,3,5 | CCcount, CHKCount, SACount |
| 102 | 2021-02-03 | 1,3,1 | CCcount, CHKCount, SACount |
| 103 | 2019-04-12 | 4,0,2 | CCount, SACount |

As you can see, I used STUFF, but not sure if that's the right approach. I need the Product Mix showing the count and Product Mix Expanded in the worded format.
Feel free to ask questions you need more inputs. Thank you in advance.

Comment: your link is broken.

Comment: Let me check, try this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=267c46fdc71a59a8c879687cabf4458a

Comment: worded format == CCount, CHKCount, SACount, i would prefer CCCount + CHKCount + SACount if possible.

Comment: Don't put a link to a fiddle for your attempts, put them (the *actual* code) in the question.

Comment: Ok let me edit it

Comment: Also, all `STUFF` does is replaces a section of a string with another, what does it have to do with the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample data and expected results does the following work for you?

```
select CustomerKey, ProcessDate, Concat(CCcount,',',CHKcount,',',SACount) Product_Mix, 
    Concat(case when CCcount>0 then 'CCcount' else '' end,', ',
    case when CHKcount>0 then 'CHKcount' else '' end, ', ',
    case when SACount>0 then 'SACount' else '' end) Product_Mix_Expanded
from products
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method via XQuery.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    Customerkey int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    processdate date NULL,
    CCcount int NULL,
    CHKcount int NULL,
    SACount int NULL
);
INSERT INTO @tbl (Customerkey, processdate, CCcount, CHKCount, SACount) VALUES
(101,'20210501', 12,3,5),
(102,'20210203', 1,3,1),
(103,'20190412', 4,0,2);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT Customerkey, processdate
    , REPLACE(x.query('data(/root/*)').value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'), SPACE(1), ',') AS Product_Mix
    , REPLACE(x.query('for $x in /root/*[./text()!="0"]
    return local-name($x)').value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'), SPACE(1), ',') AS Product_Mix_Expanded
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT CCcount, CHKCount, SACount
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t(x);
```

**Output**

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------+
| Customerkey | processdate | Product_Mix |   Product_Mix_Expanded   |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------+
|         101 | 2021-05-01  |      12,3,5 | CCcount,CHKCount,SACount |
|         102 | 2021-02-03  |       1,3,1 | CCcount,CHKCount,SACount |
|         103 | 2019-04-12  |       4,0,2 | CCcount,SACount          |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: @Anu, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. It is very simple, no CASE statements, no extra commas, and column names are picked up automatically.

Comment: this worked for me, i want to add another element(Product_bal) , could you please refer to some links that could help, what I found didn't help. Thank you.

Comment: @Anu, unfortunately, it is not clear what you are asking without a minimal reproducible example. Please ask a new question.

Comment: Sure, will do soon.