# How to add 2 columns/multiple elements FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```sql
CREATE TABLE Products
(
    Customerkey int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    processdate date NULL,
    CCcount int NULL,
    CHKcount int NULL,
    SACount int NULL,
    VEHCount int NULL, 
    LoanCount int NULL,  
    MortCount int NULL
);

INSERT INTO products (Customerkey, processdate, CCcount, CHKCount, SACount, VEHCount, LoanCount,  MortCount) 
VALUES (101, '20210501', 12, 3, 5, 1, 3, 1),
       (102, '20210203', 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0),
       (103, '20190412', 4, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1)

SELECT 
    Customerkey, processdate,
    REPLACE(x.query('data(/root/*)').value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'), SPACE(1), ',') AS Product_Mix,
    REPLACE(x.query('for $x in /root/*[./text()!=""]
    return local-name($x)').value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'), SPACE(1), '+') AS Product_Mix_Expanded
FROM 
    @tbl
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT CCcount, CHKCount, SACount
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t(x);
```

I want LoanProduct_Mix for these VEHCount, LoanCount,  MortCount. This is from this link
[SQL Server 2016: how to get a single row view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911267/sql-server-2016-how-to-get-a-single-row-view/67911564?noredirect=1#comment120366112_67911564)

Expected output:

| CustomerKey | processdate | Product_Mix | Product_Mix_Expanded | LoanProduct_Mix |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2021-05-01 | 12,3,5 | CCcount+CHKCount+SACount | VEHCount+LoanCount+MortCount |
| 102 | 2021-02-03 | 1,3,1 | CCcount+CHKCount+SACount |  |
| 103 | 2019-04-12 | 4,0,2 | CCount + SACount | LoanCount + MortCount |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution for SQL Server 2012 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    Customerkey int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    processdate date NULL,
    CCcount int NULL,
    CHKcount int NULL,
    SACount int NULL,
    VEHCount int NULL, 
    LoanCount int NULL,  
    MortCount int NULL
);
INSERT INTO @tbl (Customerkey, processdate, CCcount, CHKCount, SACount, VEHCount, LoanCount,  MortCount) 
VALUES (101, '20210501', 12, 3, 5, 1, 3, 1),
       (102, '20210203', 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0),
       (103, '20190412', 4, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1)
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT Customerkey, processdate
    , REPLACE(x.query('data(/root/*)').value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'), SPACE(1), ',') AS Product_Mix
    , REPLACE(x.query('for $x in /root/*[./text()!="0"]
        return local-name($x)').value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'), SPACE(1), '+') AS Product_Mix_Expanded
    , REPLACE(y.query('for $x in /root/*[./text()!="0"]
        return local-name($x)').value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'), SPACE(1), '+') AS LoanProduct_Mix
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT CCcount, CHKCount, SACount
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(x)
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT VEHCount, LoanCount, MortCount
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t2(y);
```

**Output**

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------+------------------------------+
| Customerkey | processdate | Product_Mix |   Product_Mix_Expanded   |       LoanProduct_Mix        |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------+------------------------------+
|         101 | 2021-05-01  |      12,3,5 | CCcount+CHKCount+SACount | VEHCount+LoanCount+MortCount |
|         102 | 2021-02-03  |       1,3,1 | CCcount+CHKCount+SACount | NULL                         |
|         103 | 2019-04-12  |       4,0,2 | CCcount+SACount          | LoanCount+MortCount          |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason for XML here. `CONCAT_WS` with some `CASE` expressions seems to do the job nicely:

```sql
SELECT Customerkey,
       processdate,
       CONCAT_WS(',',CCcount,CHKcount,SACount) AS ProductMix,
       CONCAT_WS(' + ',CASE WHEN CCcount> 0 THEN 'CCcount' END,CASE WHEN CHKcount> 0  THEN 'CHKcount' END,CASE WHEN SACount> 0  THEN 'SACount' END) AS ProductMixExpanded,
       CONCAT_WS(' + ',CASE WHEN VEHCount> 0 THEN 'VehCount' END,CASE WHEN LoanCount> 0  THEN 'LoanCount' END,CASE WHEN MortCount> 0  THEN 'MortCount' END) AS LoanProductMix
FROM dbo.Products;
```

Comment: The OP has SQL Server 2016. The `CONCAT_WS()` function is not available.

Comment: No I, it was added in 2017, but the OP hasn't noted their version above @YitzhakKhabinsky, so I *assume* they are using the latest tools.